# Не получается сформировать ссылку. Помогите!

Tags: javascript

Добрейшего вечерочка)
Что я делаю не так?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = $("name").val();
  var cost = $("cost").val();
  var comment = $("comment").val();
  var tmp = "site.ru/?x" + name + "&z=" + cost + "&y=" + comment;
  var result = encodeURI(tmp);
  $("textarea#tar1").html(result);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" name="input1">
<input type="text" id="cost" name="input2">
<input type="text" id="comment" name="input3">
<textarea id="tar1" rows="9"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Получаю в результате вместо ссылки с переменными:

```html
site.ru/?xundefined&z=undefined&y=undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Забыли расставить в селекторах знак, обозначающий id(`#`).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var cost = $("#cost").val();
  var comment = $("#comment").val();
  var tmp = "site.ru/?x" + name + "&z=" + cost + "&y=" + comment;
  var result = encodeURI(tmp);
  $("textarea#tar1").html(result);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" name="input1">
<input type="text" id="cost" name="input2">
<input type="text" id="comment" name="input3">
<textarea id="tar1" rows="9"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе старина! Хорошего вечера!